# How can I open my node.js program in chrome? - VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, client-server, visual-studio-code

I'm new to node.js, and VS Code. I'm watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYOltVz7kL0), and the issue is that in the video, he runs his server. I can do this fine, but, when he opens his browser and types http://localhost:8888, he can connect to the server like he is a client. When I do this, the program Emit(I think that is what its called) opens and has an error - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'h:\Microsoft VS Code\bin\index.html' at Error (native). In the beginning of the tutorial, he went to edit configurations and entered the local host url into some text box and changed other settings. Although, he is using IntelliJ, and I'm using VS Code. How can I make it so I can enter the url and run as a client.

[EDIT]: When I try to start without debugging, I get the options select enviornment - Chrome or Node.js. Also, I went to the terminal and typed node app(file name is App.js), and I get the error in the terminal - module.js: 471. throw err. Error: cannot find module at C:Users\Name\App

Thank you.

Comment: You only need to execute your .js file into node, so a command prompt you should type something like `node myprogram.js` and it should start running.

Comment: you ninja'd me, does your file is inside the path you typed? probably you are trying to execute the file but is not inside that path

Comment: That could be it, thanks for the help!